# Record movie with UIImage overlay

Tags: iphone, ios

I have made quite a few camera apps either for taking picture or making a movie so I am familiar with that code.

What I would like to do is when I initiate a camera, I create an overlay of a UIImage view with an image of a mustache in it. Now I tell the user that he can record a video and make sure mustache picture that he sees on the screen shows up over his face and then he should record a video. In terms of coding I know how to do this too.

The problem I have is that I have no idea how can I combine the video and that picture overlay? I mean when the video gets recorded it records only what the camera see (user face without mustache). What I want to do is make a funny video with that image of mustache placed on the video as well?

Here is one [sample app](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/duck-dynasty-face-cam-create/id687962133?mt=8&ign-mpt=uo=4) that does something similar. How do they do that? Any sample tutorial?

Comment: This tutorial show how to record video overlays: [AVFoundation Tutorial: Adding Overlays and Animations to Videos](http://www.raywenderlich.com/30200/avfoundation-tutorial-adding-overlays-and-animations-to-videos)

Comment: @MarcusAdams Thank you for pointing me in the right direction.